# How do I dynamically add a set of columns based on an input parameter?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I need to add or remove roughly 20 columns based on variouse input parameters. I know I can wrap each line in the CASE statement, but when I need to add 10 columns for column set 10 that's a ton of extra code.  Is the answer to make a dynamic SQL monster?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do - return 5 specific columns when the end user needs Column Set 1:

```
DECLARE @AddColumns AS NVARCHAR(20) = 'Column Set 1'

SELECT 
    col1
    , col2
    , CASE WHEN @AddColumns = 'Column Set 1' OR @AddColumns = 'Include All Columns'
        THEN col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
    END 
    , CASE WHEN @AddColumns = 'Column Set 2' OR @AddColumns = 'Include All Columns'
        THEN col8, col9, col10
    END
    , col11

FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just want to select all the columns and then deal with it on the client?

Comment: @Conrad, I'm consuming the dataset in VB, so that's a good idea, but the if..thens to remove the rows from the dataset get's messy because I have such long lists of column names to remove.

Comment: Well if that's the case your two options are 1) a big IF statements that executes different queries based on input, or 2) calls to sp_executeSQL. The big downside with both these approaches is that the tooling around queries with dynamic columns isn't that great.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with a dynamically built SQL string (CDATA) in VB. So I have a SELECT block, IF logic to add column set 1, another IF for CS2, etc. and then the WHERE clause. That seems to be the easiest way to do it in this case.  I'll add notes to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weighing the options of dynamic SQL, ExecuteSql, building the SQL string in VB, or editing the resulting VB dataset I went with dynamically building the SQL string in VB. I was looking for an 'easy' way to do this in SQL. Although it is possible to do in SQL, it is 'cleaner' for me to do it in VB. (Sorry I should have mentioned the query is being used by VB in the original question.)  Imagine many column sets with each set adding roughly 5-10 columns, multiple joins, parameterized filters, etc.  What I do here if build various SQL query parts and them append them together based on the input parameters.

```
' Build the various chunks of SQL as CDATA strings
Dim selectPrimaryColumns As String =
<![CDATA[
    /*
        My Report
    */
    USE DatabaseName

    SELECT col1
        , col2
]]>.Value

selectColumnSetA
<![CDATA[
        -- Column Set A
        , col3
        , col4
]]>.Value

selectColumnSetB
<![CDATA[
        -- Column Set B
        , col5
        , col6
]]>.Value

Dim selectFilters As String =
<![CDATA[
    FROM MyTable t
      -- with many joins

    WHERE t.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDAte)
      -- and many more parameterized filters.

]]>.Value

' Set the first part of the query
Dim fullQuery As String = selectPrimaryColumns

' Conditionally add the various column sets
SELECT CASE myParameter
 CASE "ColumnSetA"
    fullQuery = fullQuery & selectColumnSetA
 CASE "ColumnSetB"
    fullQuery = fullQuery & selectColumnSetB

' Add the last part of the query
fullQuery = fullQuery & selectFilters
```

I now have a SQL query string that I can pass to the SQL Command object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @AddColumns AS NVARCHAR(20) = 'Column Set 1'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(5000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT   col1, col2 '
IF @AddColumns = 'Column Set 1' OR @AddColumns = 'Include All Columns'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ', col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 '
IF @AddColumns = 'Column Set 2' OR @AddColumns = 'Include All Columns'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ', col8, col9, col10 '
SET @SQL = @SQL + ',col11 FROM MyTable'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: calling [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) would be preferred, in the likely event that there's going to parameters in the where clause to avoid quoting, escaping and SQL injection headaches